# Vue.js stylesheets resources

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I recently discovered Vue.js. 
I use it with the single file component architecture and I noticed that all my components' styles are all loaded in the page (even those which are not active).

Is there a way to only load current components' CSS, and avoid code repetition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scoped` attribute to make styles only apply to the current element:

```
<style scoped>
  .class{
    //will only apply to this component
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I have already tested, but the use of "scoped" add an attribute to the main HTML element of the target component and the scoped style use this attribute to select. However, it is still loaded on the same page if the component is not active.

Comment: Like @Cohars said, I think having one minified CSS file is the best for your app.  Loading CSS via an HTTP request every time you loaded a new component wouldn't be an optimal solution.

Comment: why would you want to load and unload CSS all the time? Are you worried about rendering performance?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack will [concat and minify](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) all your sources (even if they are scoped).

> *CSS across all components extracted into a single file and minified with cssnano.*

I don't really see the use case where you'ld need to split your CSS into separate files.